# How to position label.new() more specific, vertically? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's my label, messing with the candles:

[image: Label messing with the candles]

```
label.new(bar_index, high, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, text="Blah Blah")
```

How to position it higher, to get out behind the candles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify the `yloc` argument of `label.new()`, it will use the `price` you pass in the second argument -which in your case is `high`. That's why the label points exactly to the high price.

You can use the `yloc` argument with something like `yloc.abovebar` (`lbl_red` below) or you can use a mathematical formula together with the price (`lbl_green` below).

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
is_red = close < open
is_green = not is_red

_atr = ta.atr(10) / 4

var label lbl_red = na
var label lbl_green = na

if (barstate.islast)
    lbl_red := label.new(bar_index, high, "Test", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.white)
    lbl_green := label.new(bar_index, low - _atr, "Test", color=color.green, style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=color.white)

    label.delete(lbl_red[1])
    label.delete(lbl_green[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you need the label Y distance rather consistent use the highest value and lowest value of a certain amount of bars and add a percentage of (highest - lowest) to the candle high

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).